# How to get a formalized list of columns in the result table of a stored procedure?

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure that returns a table with many columns and rows.

I would like to continue working with the table described above using SQL queries or connections.

I assume I need to create a temporary table and insert the resulting table from the stored procedure into it.

The set of columns in both of the above tables must be the same.
How do I quickly create a temporary table with a large set of columns that matches the set of columns from the result table of the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

SELECT * INTO #TEMPTABLE FROM ORIGINALTABLE WHERE 1=2